# CKeditor return "CKEditor is not defined" in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ckeditor

When integrating CKeditor in Laravel. It returns error:

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/control/post/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEditor is not defined
    at add:88

This is my code:

```
<script src="vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor1" ></textarea>

 <script>
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
 </script>
```

There are questions with the same problem, but none helped me

Answer (score 2):

You must first publish vendor with:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor
```

And then use the asset helper function to address the script file:

```
  <script src="{{asset('vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}"></script>
```

or

```
  <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

This happened because You forgot to add a forward slash before referencing the js file. this way browser addresses it from where your page currently at. so use slash before the address or use the asset helper function

This should print out this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js (correct)
```

Instead of this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/control/post/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js (wrong)
```

Comment: Salar Bahador, i edit it how you suggested. But i take the same error with print:          http://127.0.0.1:8000/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js

Comment: did you publish the vendor? @IsmoilovAmir

Comment: Salar Bahador, i did it. Publishing complete

Comment: @IsmoilovAmir is vendor directory created in public directory?

Comment: Salar Bahador, yes i have directory vendor in public directory. But there no ckeditor's data. All data of ckeditor are located in root/vendor/unisharp

Comment: @IsmoilovAmir So the problem is located here. after publishing the vendor,laravel must create vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor in public directory. try this: type "php artisan vendor:publish" without any tag. after that press 0 to install all vendors. check if the directory exists and keep me updated

Comment: Salar Bahador, i did it. But it not create unisharp durectory in public directory

Comment: @IsmoilovAmir whats the directory then? if the answer is useful please upvote and select it as best answer. thank you

Comment: Salar Bahador, it's doesn't work. Even after copying unisharp directry to public directory. Now i take error:     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined
    at a (ckeditor.js:322)
    at Object.CKEDITOR.replace (ckeditor.js:326)
    at add:89

Answer (score -1):

use this script  `<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.6/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>`
and after your text area write

```
 <script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' ); </script>
```

it will works with you